# How can I get cache statistics for a particular path in a cloudfront distribution

Tags: wordpress, amazon-web-services, caching, amazon-cloudfront, amazon-elb

I'm having a cloudfront distribution for a domain and I want to see the hit and miss cache statistics for a particular url (with particular path).

Currently the in aws console, I can only get the cache statistic for a entire distribution individually. This is the doc for the same
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/cache-statistics.html

I want get the hit and miss ratio for a URL, like this https://example.com/path/to/see/
Is there any other tool I can use of

I have tried getting the report from aws console but it doesn't give option to choose a particular path
[this is the statistic for entire distribution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AU39O.png)

Comment: As I know is not possible to have metrics for a specific url. It's possible to see the most popular one with "popular objects".
I think you can enable the Cloudfornt logs and extract the statistics from them

Answer (score 1):

If the url is in a popular object you can see the statics there as mentioned in the comment by Danilo. But if URL is not part of a popular object you need to enable the Cloudfront logs and then setup Athena to query the logs. The below query will give you the cache static for a URL by hour on a particular day, it also give you cache hit ratio

```
 SELECT
    hour,
    SUM(CASE WHEN result_type = 'Hit' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as HIT,
    SUM(CASE WHEN result_type IN ('RefreshHit') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as REFRESH,
    SUM(CASE WHEN result_type IN ('Miss') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as MISS,
    100.0 * SUM(CASE WHEN result_type = 'Hit' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) / COUNT(*) as Cache_perc,
    COUNT(*)
FROM <table name>
WHERE
        host_header = '<domain_name>'
    AND year = '<year>'
    AND month = '<Month>'
    AND day = '<Date>'
AND URI ='<your uri>'
GROUP BY
    hour
ORDER BY
    hour
```

Comment: More information about how to set up Athena querying of S3 logs: https://repost.aws/knowledge-center/analyze-logs-athena